# Black screen with Unity launcher and dash after startup

Tags: unity, compiz

[image]

I see this after doing `sudo shutdown -r` previously. Looks like compiz/unity is broken for some reason. I also tried to `rm -rf ~/.cache ~/.config` and reinstalled unity, didn't take any effect.

By the way, when I do Alt-Tab on this setup, for a moment, right while switching windows, it does a glitch.. it like flashes with desktop for a ms, quite annoying. How can I fight it?